# How to reduce number of documents to be sync from a mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, synchronization, nosql

In my current project, I am using two databases.

1. A MongoDB instance gathering data from different data providers (abt 15M documents)
2. Another (relational) database instance holding only the data which is needed for the application, i.e. a subset of the data in the MongoDB instance. (abt 5M rows)

As part of the synchronisation process, I need to regularly check for new entries in the MongoDB depending on data in the relational DB.

Let's say, this is about songs and artists, a document in the MongoDB might look like this:

```
{_id:1,artists:["Simon","Garfunkel"],"name":"El Condor Pasa"}
```

Part of the sync process is to import/update all songs from those artists that already exist in the relational DB, which are currently about 1M artists.

So how do I retrieve all songs of 1M named artists from MongoDB for import?

My first thought (and try) was to over all artists and query all songs for each artist (of course, there's an index on the "artists" field). But this takes several minutes for each batch of 1.000 artists, which would make this process a long runner.

My second thought was to write all existing artists to a separate mongoDB collection and have a super query which only retrieves songs of artists that are stored in there. But so far I have not been able retrieve data based on two collections.
Is this a good use case for map/reduce? If yes, can someone pls. give me a hint on how to achieve this? (I am not completely new to NoSQL, but sort of a newbie when it comes to map/reduce.)
Or is this idea just crazy and I have to stick with a process that's running for several days?

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Comment: Retrieving documents from Mongo should be fairly fast. Is it reading 1000 artists data taking a lot of time or is it updating the relational DB that is consuming a lot of time ?

Comment: These test runs did not write anything to the relational DB. I queried batches of 1.000 from the relational DB (which takes a few seconds, mainly because I am currently retrieving the complete entity, not only the names). After that, I query MongoDB 1.000 times (once for each artist) to retrieve their songs. I think it is the mass of single queries taking the time, which is why I would prefer to have this done server-side (i.e. MongoDB-side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you regularly need to check for changes, then add a timestamp to your data, and incorporate that timestamp into your query. For example, if you add a "created_ts" attribute, then you can look for records that were created since the last time your batch ran.

Here are a few ideas for making the mongo interaction more efficient:

- Reduce network overhead by using an ["in" query](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24in). Play around with the size of the array of artist IDs in order to determine what works best for your case.
- Reduce network overhead by only selecting or reading the attributes that you need.
- Make sure that your documents are [indexed](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Indexes) by artist.
- On the Mongo server, make sure that as much of your data fits into memory as possible. Retrieving data from disk is going to be slow no matter what else you do. If it doesn't fit into memory, then you have a few options -- buy more memory; shrink your data set (ex. drop attributes that you don't actually need); shard; etc.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable input, especially selecting only the needed fields and using $in to query with batches of artists really speeded this up. :)